# Docker container with postgres and java

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I would like a Docker Postgres container with Java.
Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres AS postgres

FROM openjdk
COPY --from=postgres . .
```

I don't get any errors. But when I execute `java -version` it says

> command not found

I also tried this:

```
FROM postgres
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

But I get the error

```
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

What did I do wrong? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this could help you : https://hub.docker.com/r/alinous/docker-java-postgresql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished it with following Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre-headless
```